# Android - 9 patch image drawing incorrectly - only from builds of some machines

Tags: android, android-image

I have a 9 patch image which is being used from an external library as a background for a button.

Only on builds from some machines 2 out of 4 team, the 9 patch is not rendering correctly.  You can see the black around the outside, it looks very strange!

I deleted the gen folder and rebuild - no success!

[image: button]

Comment: Are all team members using the same version of the Android SDK tools?

Comment: name of the 9-patch image should be "image_name.9.png"  (jpg etc), maybe you just forgot to name it like this.  If not post you 9-patch image here.

Comment: @alamaz, its from a well established library, I don't really want to go editing it myself.

Comment: @GrahamBorland perhaps not, thats my current train of thought, something to do with versions - investigating further

Comment: looks like we both have 20.0.3

Comment: One of the guys who doesnt get the problem is on 20.0.1 and platform tools v 13 instead of my 20.0.3 and 14

Comment: I think something was corrupt, i redownloaded the original source library and it works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the the files were corrupt as replacing the library fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on a team project, the 9-patch files in the library were broken and behaving as normal drawables and one of the app projects had working 9-patch replacements. I just moved the working files to the library and that fixed it.